# Explain regsub invocations

Tags: tcl, expect, regsub

```
regsub -all "\\\\033" $cmd "\033" cmd
[regsub -all "\\\\c" $cmd "" cmd]
regsub -all "\\\\$i" $cmd [lindex $exp_out $i] cmd
```

Can someone explain meaning of these three statements?
They are three different statements.

Comment: See manual of [Tcl syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) and the [regsub command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/regsub.htm).

Answer (score 1):

> `regsub -all "\\\\033" $cmd "\033" cmd`

This replaces all instances of a backslash followed by `033` with the ASCII <kbd>ESC</kbd> character. It reads the string to process from the `cmd` variable and writes it back to that variable.

> `[regsub -all "\\\\c" $cmd "" cmd]`

This replaces all instances of a backslash followed by `c` with the empty string (effectively deleting it). It updates the `cmd` variable. It substitutes into its calling context the number of substitutions performed.

> `regsub -all "\\\\$i" $cmd [lindex $exp_out $i] cmd`

This one's a bit more complex. For a particular numeric index, stored in the `i` variable, it replaces all instances of a backslash followed by the index with the `i`'th element (counting from 0) of the list in `exp_out`. It updates the `cmd` variable.

Comment: There are four backslashes in those regular expressions because they are being quoted _twice_, once for Tcl and once for the RE engine itself.

Comment: This replaces all instances of a backslash followed by 033 with the ASCII ESC character. It reads the string to process from the cmd variable and writes it back to that variable. Can you clarify this please? I don't have 033 in my cmd

Comment: expect_out($j,string), Can you clarify about this? How many previously matched outputs will be saved?

Comment: If there are no instances of a given substring in a string, replacing them all doesn't change anything. You know, _usual behaviour of ALL in computing_.

Comment: And I think you should ask a separate question about `$expect_out($j,string)`; that's both not in the original question and worth its own as it is rather tied into how Expect works.